# Yii2 kartik-v gridview: TypeError: jQuery(...).editable is not a function

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

When the very FIRST time insert the first new data into the gridview (no data from database in gridview at this moment), all the Editable columns appeared as malfunctioned button instead of working link. After refresh the page, the Editable column in the Gridview appeared as link as expected and working.

Why there is only the first time it has this problem?

This is the shown error after insert the very first new data into the Gridview.

**TypeError: jQuery(...).editable is not a function**

This is my column:

```
             [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
                'attribute' => 'short_desc',
                'refreshGrid' => true,
                'editableOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
                    return [
                        'header'=>'short_desc',
                        'size'=>'md',

                    ];
                }
            ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around my code to refresh the page even after pjax reload WHEN there is only ONE data(first data).

In my jquery function of addNewData(), I added the codes below after pjax reload after new data added successfully:

```
<?php                       
     $models = $dataProvider->getModels(); // get dataProvider to check if there is any data

     // refresh whole page for the first newly added data when there is only one data as in Editable Column not initiated when there is no data
     if( count($models) < 1 || $models == null || !isset($models) )                         
     {
 ?>
         window.location.reload();
 <?php                              
     }                      
 ?>
```

This is works for me now.